# Executing multiple functions in a laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal adaptive payments within laravel.

I want to use something similar to this code:
http://proggblo.blogspot.ca/2013/04/paypal-adaptive-payments-parallel.html

Problem is, I wouldn't be too sure how to do that within laravel. Would I use a controller and pass through a post request? If so, how would it look like? Something like this?
Route:

```
Route::post('/payment', [
'uses' => '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\PaypalController@payment',
'as' => 'quote.payment',
]);
```

controller:

```
class PaypalController extends Controller {
  public function payment(Request $request) {


  $apiUrl = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/";

  $paypalUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";


   function __construct() {

       $this->headers = array(

          "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".API_USER,

          "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".API_PASS,

          "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".API_SIG,

          "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",   

          "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",

          "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".APP_ID  

      );

  }  
    function _paypalSend($data,$call) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl.$call);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);

    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);      


  }
 }
}
```

etc. etc. Leaving the rest of the code out. (you can find it in the link above)

Now this would would fine if the functions within the payment function would execute.

Should I use middleware instead of a controller in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It would be no different than executing multiple methods in standard PHP. Just create your methods inside the controller and you can call them all whenever you want to.

The biggest problem in your controller is you have a __construct method nested inside your payment function. Also, if you are hitting the payment endpoint on the POST request, you need access to the $data and $call variables inside that method in order to send the payment.Since you don't show where the data comes from of those variables, I can only you show you in theory how to do this

```
class PaypalController extends Controller 
{
    private $apiUrl;
    private $paypalUrl;

    public function payment(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->apiUrl = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/";
        $this->paypalUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";

        $this->send($data, $call);
    }

    private function send($data, $call)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl . $call);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->getHeaders());
        return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);      
    }


    private function getHeaders()
    {
        return [

            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".API_USER,

            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".API_PASS,

            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".API_SIG,

            "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",   

            "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",

            "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".APP_ID  

        ];
    }
}
```